# List constructor for async gen

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, list-comprehension

What method is better or they similar?

```
l = list(async_gen)
```

or

```
l = [i async for i in async_gen]
```

where async_gen is any object has a aiter method

Comment: *"Better"* how? If you're concerned about performance, have you tried timing or profiling it?

Comment: Yes, it can be benchmarked, but creating useful and comprehensive test cases is too hard. I would like to see some theoretic sources with behavior writed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only second variant works.
Asynchronous generators does not support to_list method